# Equivalent of Controller.Read() in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to send the files in filestreams of size more than 800 MB from controller to UI.

Is there any method to send the filestream from controller to browser in ***chunks***.

because  if I use

```
File(downloadStream, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
```

is taking system memory and not able to send it to UI.

Please suggest the most efficient way of sending the filestream in chunks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FilePathResult, which uses HttpResponse.TransmitFile to write the file directly to the  http. This method doesn't buffer the file in memory on the server, so it should be a better option for sending larger files.

Check out its implementation [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/125/ASP.NET-MVC-Uploading-and-Downloading-Files)

Comment: If suppose I use FilestreamResult i.e., public Filestreamresult Download()         {      return File(downloadStream, "application/octet-stream", fileName);       } ,can I call the Download() on click of a button like this @Html.ActionLink("FileDownload", "Download", new { file = item.FileName, GuID = item.DocumentGuID }) /text).Width(10); ???

Comment: Why can not you call it. Download would be some action method on some controller. While rendering an Action link, you provide 4 things basically, Inner Text for the link, name of the controller, name of the action method, parameter. I do not see why you can not call it. Did you try to call it in your code ???